# Grouping of date fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to select rows from the database

```
$date=mysql_query("SELECT party_id, advo_id, max(fixed_date) as d FROM `case_proceeding` group by party_id order by fixed_date");
```

```
    while($drow=mysql_fetch_array($date)){  

    if($drow['d']<$today){

        $decide=mysql_query("select * from case_decision where party_id='$drow[party_id]'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($decide)=='0')
        {

            if($drow['d']!='0000-00-00')
            {
                echo '<a href=case-tracking.php?date='.$drow['d'].'&party_id='.$drow['party_id'].'&advo_id='.$drow['advo_id'].' style=color:#000000;>'.date('d/m/Y',strtotime($drow['d'])).'</a>';
            }

        }
```

there are many rows that has same fixed_date.

eg. party_id=1 has fixed_date=2012-08-12
and party_id=5 has also the same date fixed_date=2012-08-12

now I want to make groups of the rows that have same fixed_date.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.party_id, t2.advo_id, t1.MaxDate
FROM
(
    SELECT party_id, 
      MAX(fixed_date) AS MaxDate 
    FROM `case_proceeding` 
    GROUP BY party_id 
) t1
INNER JOIN case_proceeding t2  ON t1.party_id = t2.party_id 
                              AND t1.MaxDate  = t2.fixed_date
ORDER BY fixed_date
```

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' - How it doesn't work, Can you please show the table structure with some sample data and how you want to get from these results?

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain amount of guesswork involved without knowing your tables & relationships, but give this a try:

SELECT cd.*, cp.party_id, cp.advo_id, cp.MaxDate
FROM
(
    SELECT party_id, advo_id, MAX(fixed_date) AS MaxDate 
    FROM `case_proceeding` 
    GROUP BY party_id 
) cp
INNER JOIN case_decision cd
ON cp.party_id = cd.party_id 
ORDER BY cp.MaxDate